# Custom Login using xAuth?

Tags: facebook, twitter, authentication, oauth, xauth

In our project, we want to give the user the option to only fill out one login screen, then the app should check many social networks for this email & password combination and log the user in accordingly.
However, the problem we are facing is with oAuth, which only allows for default login screen.

I heard about it would be possible for Twitter when getting a xAuth certificate from them (hard to get ?)

How's about facebook, linked in ?

Anyone knows how to get this done ?

Thanks, we are stuck with this already for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Most challenging issue you have is the most of the service provider be it OpenID/OAuth enabled will not let you search there system with what you are trying to access.

Even some of the system like Twitter/LinkedIn never give you back user email id they treat it as a security issue (Though they call it as design specifications :))

So i am afraid it is possible.For getting XAuth for Twitter

```
To use xAuth, send a request to api@twitter.com with plenty 
of details about your application and why xAuth is the best choice for it.
```

here are more details
[XAuth Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth)

But even twiter XAuth is almost same as OAuth.XAuth is still in its early stage.One way is to ask user for the email and than based on the domain redirect user to the particular system and let user authorize themself, but personally that is kind of heck and not a good solution at all.

Why user will fill his username and password of other service in your login screen?? don't you think that's something beat the whole idea of security

Comment: Well,
1. They don't have to "give back" a email address (e.g. if it's right or not) in the login process.
2. Yes, have viewed that xauth page already. I was more asking anyone who had already got a xAuth certificate, if it was hard to get. "send as much info about your app" is not very exact ..
3. We don't want to use the normal default login (e.g. UIwebview) as it just doesn't fit our design.
4. We also want to save time for the user, by not having to login into every social net manually but make a "bulk login" automatically into all networks where the user uses the same password and email.